# How to plot a chart with text variables using plotly dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a df that looks like this:

[image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQZp2.png)

my goal is to make a line chart that sums up the codes for each month and, after this, add a dropdown to be able to filter between 'type', group' and 'Spec.'

If I didn't want the dropdown filter, I could achieve this with

```
`df.groupby('month')['code'].count().reset_index()`
```

Since I need the filters, the ideal is to be able to do this sum in the graph code in plotly, so I don't lose the 'type', group' and 'Spec.' columns.

I tryed this code:

```
`line_fig1 = px.line(data_frame = df,
    x= 'month',
    y='code',
    labels={'month':'','code':''},
    title='',
    width=450,
    height=250,
    template='plotly_white',
    color_discrete_sequence= ["rgb(1, 27, 105)"],
    markers=True,
    text='code'
    )`
```

and this was the result:

[image of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw5h7.png)

I also tryed something like

```
`line_fig1 = px.line(data_frame = df,
    x= 'month',
    y='code'.count()`
```

or even tryed to add a column with a number one, so the chart could aggregate

```
`df['assign_value'] = 1 

line_fig1 = px.line(data_frame = df,
    x= 'month',
    y='assign_value'`
```

But this also don't work.

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should groupby by month and code and then use new dataframe to make line graph. Something as below:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['month', 'code'])['code'].count().reset_index(name='counts')
fig = px.line(df2,x='month',y='counts', color='code')
fig.show()
```

[image]